# Custom Database Type in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, earthdistance

I am using Rails 3.1.1 with PostgreSQL 9.1 and the [earthdistance module](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/earthdistance.html).
To be able to calculate the distance between different locations properly, I have setup a column with the `earth` type in my `branches` table.

The problem I am experiencing now is that my Rails application that uses this table does not understand the earth type and thus I am getting this in my `db/schema.rb`:

```
# Could not dump table "branches" because of following StandardError
#   Unknown type 'earth' for column 'location'
```

This is problematic since now I can't create my test database from the schema.rb.

**How can I add this type to AR or make it ignore that column?**

Comment: Found the answer to the question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383058/rails-schema-creation-problem

Comment: It's helpful to others to write out an answer to even your own question and accept it.  It also takes this question off of the unanswered list.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

Change you config/application.rb

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

This will change the output format to the native PostgreSQL SQL format, schema.rb will be disabled and a new file will be generated /db/config/structure.sql

Comment: I did try this, but rails `db:schema:load` still seems to look for the `schema.rb` file.

Comment: Looks like you have to use `rake db:structure:load` instead.

Answer (score 18):

Another case where someone might run into this is when inserting your custom types (enums) into PostgreSQL. If one does this and still wants to dump your schema.rb without using the SQL dumper, you can add custom database types to the adapter's list of valid types.

---

**Update 2021-08-13:** Commenter points out there might be an easier way to do this than my suggestion below.

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES[:my_custom_type] = { name: "my_custom_type_name" }
```

---

## Original Suggestion

For example, let's say you have a `Customer` with a `status` and `priority` and you want to use postgres's native enum types. You will need to do some setup manually in your migration and you'll need an initializer to help Rails generate your schema.

### The Migration

```
class CreateCustomers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]

  def up
    execute <<-SQL
      CREATE TYPE type_status AS ENUM ('active', 'inactive');
      CREATE TYPE type_priority AS ENUM ('high', 'medium','low');
    SQL

    create_table :customers do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.column :status, :type_status
      t.column :priority, :type_priority
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :customer_addresses
    execute <<-SQL
      DROP TYPE status;
      DROP TYPE priority;
    SQL
  end
end
```

### The initializer.

```
# config/initializers/postres_custom_enum_types.rb

# Following only needed if the adapater isn't loaded for some reason - e.g. 
# if you have no models in your app. 
require "active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter"

module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters
    if const_defined?(:PostgreSQLAdapter)
      class PostgreSQLAdapter
        NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES.merge!(
          enum:    { name: 'enum' },
          # there is a chance the above causes conflicts in some cases, you can
          # always be more explicit and actually use your type or names (I am not looking up which)
          # type_priority:    { name: 'enum' }
        )
      end
    end
  end
end
```

### Validation of this solution

This is what you will see in your DB.

```
enum_in_db_development=# INSERT INTO customers VALUES (1, 'Mario','active','high');
INSERT 0 1
enum_in_db_development=# INSERT INTO customers VALUES (1, 'Mario','active','notthere');
ERROR:  invalid input value for enum type_priority: "nothere"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO customers VALUES (1, 'Mario','active','notthere')
                                                          ^
enum_in_db_development=# SELECT enum_range(NULL::type_priority);
    enum_range     
-------------------
 {high,medium,low}
(1 row)
```

Notes about my solution:

- I am checking the existence of the `PostgreSQLAdpater` because of the way a static analysis gem I'm using partially loads some AR dependencies - specifically the gem `annotate`.
- The source for the original definition of NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES [is here for rails 6](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.0.1/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb#L101).

**Background on my running into this:** When this happened to me in rails 5.0.x, the migrations ran fine, but then my test environment would fail when trying to run `db:test:prepare` or `db:reset`. It took me quite a while to track this down to the schema dump issue.

Comment: This isn't working for me in Rails 4.2.8, is there some other formulation that I need to use?

Comment: Can you share more info on the error your running into and maybe put your code in a gist and look me to it?

Comment: I ran exactly what you typed and it's not working in 5.0.1 either

Comment: Humm... I am not having any issues I'm my project, but I also edited the above to be more generic. Can you please be more specific specific if you need help. What isn't running exactly? Are there error messages? Please make it easy on other developers when they try to help you.

Comment: The schema dump works, but the actual column is not a PG enum. Instead, it's a regular `character varying` so you can insert whatever you like as there's no enum data integrity check :(

Comment: Even after adding postres_enum_custom_types.rb, I am getting "Could not dump table "hotel_audit_rooms" because of following StandardError
#   Unknown type 'view' for column 'view'". I am using rails 5.1.2

Comment: @Rndomcoder what kind of column data type is it? This is the support list: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype.html

Comment: It is a custom data type. I have used following in migration file:- CREATE TYPE view AS ENUM ('Sea View', 'Beach View', 'None')

Comment: Did you rename the columns in the initializer? I think you've made a mistake somewhere in your code. I'd suggest carefully proofing.

Comment: Yes. I renamed the column in the in initializer.                                module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters
    if const_defined?(:PostgreSQLAdapter)
      class PostgreSQLAdapter
        NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES.merge!(
          view:  { name: 'character varying' },
        )
      end
    end
  end
end

Comment: I'd like to echo what @Uģis Ozols said. While this solution “works” as in it doesn't bomb, the resulting column will not be of the enum type, it will be a varchar column. Even the line in the resulting schema.rb will be `t.string`.

Comment: If you look at your database (not the schema), you'll see it is actually an enum type. I'll update my answer to use better naming convention than 'character varying' - not sure why I did that in the first place.

Comment: After following your example, I was off to the races. Until I ran tests. As you mention above, `db:test:prepare` causes it to blow up. Specifically, it's complaining about the `t.enum` call in my `schema.rb`. Is there anything else I need to do to get the test environment to work?

Comment: Don't use `t.enum`. Just use a normal column in the migration and specify the type.  `t.column :status, :type_status`

Comment: There seems to be an easier way to do this in the initializer: cf [ActiveRecord's PostgresqlAdapter documentation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/549ef603adcbad35776cc705a25279965f557bd5/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb#L116)

```ruby
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES[:my_custom_type] = { name: "my_custom_type_name" }
```

Comment: Thanks, @PaulB. I'll add that to the top as a potential better way.

Answer (score 4):

For anyones who comes to this page, someone has implemented this in a gem easy to use.

This is how your migration and model files will look like, respectively

```
# migration
class CreatePerson < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_enum :mood, %w(happy great never_better)

    create_table :person do |t|
      t.enum :person_mood, enum_name: :mood
    end
  end
end

# model
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum mood: { happy: 'happy', great: 'great', never_better: 'never_better' }
end
```

https://github.com/bibendi/activerecord-postgres_enum