# Newly created enum attribute throws PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "table_name" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rspec, enums, rspec-rails

I want to add the attribute "original_price_period" with type enum to my Listing model. For this I combined [ActiveRecord::Enum](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) with [PostgreSQL enum type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-enum.html).

First I added the following migration on listings table:

```
class AddRentableAndOriginalPricePeriodToListings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute <<-SQL
      CREATE TYPE original_price_period AS ENUM ('day', 'week', 'month');
    SQL

    add_column :listings, :original_price_period, :original_price_period
  end

  def down
    remove_column :listings, :original_price_period

    execute <<-SQL
      DROP TYPE original_price_period;
    SQL
  end
end
```

Then I added the declaration for the recently created enum field in Listing model:

listing.rb

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  enum original_price_period: {
    day: 'day',
    week: 'week',
    month: 'month'
  }

  ...
end
```

Everything worked fine, apparently. But when I tried to run the unit tests, they were all broken with this same message:

```
  ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
    PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "listings" does not exist
    LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"listings"'::regclass
                                              ^
    :               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                         pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                    FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                      ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
                   WHERE a.attrelid = '"listings"'::regclass
                     AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
                   ORDER BY a.attnum
  # ./spec/models/listing_spec.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
  # ./spec/models/listing_spec.rb:602:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
  # ./spec/support/database_cleaner.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
  # ./spec/support/database_cleaner.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
  # ------------------
  # --- Caused by: ---
  # PG::UndefinedTable:
  #   ERROR:  relation "listings" does not exist
  #   LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"listings"'::regclass
  #                                             ^
  #   ./spec/models/listing_spec.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I'm using Fabricators, and read somewhere it's possible they are running before the migration and this is causing the tests to fail. Still, I can't figure how to fix it. These is what I have unsuccessfully tried so far:

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
rake db:test:prepare
rake db:test:load
```

I really don't want to reset or drop and create my database, so please avoid such suggestions. Adding also here spec_helper.rb since it might be related:

spec_helper.rb

```
require 'simplecov'
require 'simplecov-json'
require 'simplecov-rcov'
require 'fantaskspec'

SimpleCov.formatters = [
    SimpleCov::Formatter::HTMLFormatter,
    SimpleCov::Formatter::JSONFormatter,
    SimpleCov::Formatter::RcovFormatter
]

SimpleCov.start
require 'webmock/rspec'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # this fixes backtraces for me, it can be removed once this change is shipped: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/pull/1616
  config.backtrace_exclusion_patterns = [
    /(?-mix:(?-mix:\/lib\/rspec\/(core|mocks|expectations|support|matchers|rails|autorun)(\.rb|\/))|rubygems\/core_ext\/kernel_require\.rb)|(?-mix:\/libd*\/ruby\/)|(?-mix:org\/jruby\/)|(?-mix:\/bin\/)|(?-mix:\/gems\/)/
  ]

  config.infer_rake_task_specs_from_file_location!

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.allow_message_expectations_on_nil = true
  end
end
```

UPDATE

Apparently the migration is failing and as a result the table "listings" is not being created. Instead, db/schema.rb shows the following message:

```
# Could not dump table "listings" because of following StandardError
#   Unknown type 'original_price_period' for column 'original_price_period'
```

Comment: What does your schema look like? The error message would leave us to believe that the listings table isn't in your test database.

Comment: good catch @Daniel, it's not creating "listings" table. Instead i get the following lines in the schema: 
# Could not dump table "listings" because of following StandardError
#   Unknown type 'original_price_period' for column 'original_price_period'

Answer (score 0):

Since PG Enums aren't natively supported in rails, your schema can't be dumped and therefore used to create your test database. You can work around this by [dumping your schema as sql](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#schema-dumping-and-you), instead of ruby.

> There are two ways to dump the schema. This is set in
>   config/application.rb by the config.active_record.schema_format
>   setting, which may be either :sql or :ruby.

I would advise against this, however, as merging sql dumps can be a painful process. Alternatively, I'd suggest just using an integer column for your enums instead of native enum types.

Comment: thanks Daniel, this looks like a valid option but I already found a workaround and it's working. You can see the details in the next answer

Answer (score 0):

The answer was found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45430348/3201684

Basically the new type is not among ActionRecord's valid types and therefore rejected when migration runs. As a workaround, an initializer is added including the new type as a valid one.