# Enumerated Types with ActiveRecord and Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/enumerated-types-with-activerecord-and-postgresql/) from SitePoint to set a model property to an Enum value, which is supported by Rails as of 4.1.

Instead of Gender Enum, I am trying to add a Season Enum.

This is the issue I get in my `schema.db`

```
# Could not dump table "semesters" because of following StandardError
#   Unknown type 'season' for column 'season'
```

This is my `migration`:

```
class AddSeasonToSemesters < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def up
    execute <<-SQL
    CREATE TYPE season AS ENUM ('fall', 'winter', 'spring', 'summer');
    SQL

    add_column :semesters, :season, :season, index: true
  end

  def down
    remove_column :semesters, :season

    execute <<-SQL
    DROP TYPE season;
    SQL
  end
end
```

And my `model` file:

```
class Semester < ApplicationRecord
  enum season: {
      fall: 'fall',
      winter: 'winter',
      spring: 'spring',
      summer: 'summer'
  }
end
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Any direction would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Since you're directly using sql statements, make sure you've `config.active_record.schema_format = :sql # default is :ruby ` in your `config/application.rb`

Comment: Yeah, this was advised in a similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45430348/4330767 Proposed another solution to keep the schema in ruby, however it doesn't seem to work as intended. Have any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

You need to switch from `db/schema.rb` to `db/structure.sql`.

The underlying problem is that `schema.rb` is a representation of the database's structure as ActiveRecord sees it but ActiveRecord doesn't understand a lot of things (such as `create type`, CHECK constraints, and other things that show up in `execute some_raw_sql` statements in migrations) that PostgreSQL does. You can `create type` all you want but `schema.rb` will never see it.

If you want to use things that ActiveRecord doesn't understand then you have to use `db/structure.sql` to store your database's structure. `structure.sql` stores the database's structure as the database understands it, not as ActiveRecord understands it.

Switching is easy:

1. Update your `config/application.rb` to contain `config.active_record.schema_format = :sql`.
2. Do a `rake db:structure:dump` to get an initial `db/structure.sql`.
3. Delete `db/schema.rb` from your directory tree and revision control.
4. Add `db/structure.sql` to revision control.
5. Adjust your rake habits:

   - Use `db:structure:dump` instead of `db:schema:dump`
   - Use `db:structure:load` instead of `db:schema:load`

That said, I'm not sure how well PostgreSQL's native `enum` types will interact with ActiveRecord as I've never done it. [AR's `enum`s](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) are a client-side translation between strings and integers but [PostgreSQL's `enum`s](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-enum.html) are handled inside the database and they don't know about each other. There might be conflicts and you will need to be sure to keep them synchronized with each other.